# count ocurrences over each day in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm having some problems figuring out how to solve but I can't come with an answer at all.This is my problem.

I have a mySQL table like the following:

```
cust_id,date_removed,station_removed,date_arrived,station_arrived
6,"2010-02-02 13:57:00",56,"2010-02-02 13:58:00",77
6,"2010-02-02 15:12:00",66,"2010-02-02 15:12:00",56
30,"2010-02-05 11:36:00",32,"2010-02-05 11:37:00",14
30,"2010-02-05 11:37:00",14,"2010-02-05 11:37:00",20
30,"2010-02-05 12:41:00",85,"2010-02-05 12:43:00",85
30,"2010-02-05 12:44:00",85,"2010-02-05 12:46:00",85
30,"2010-02-06 13:15:00",8,"2010-02-06 13:17:00",20
30,"2010-02-06 13:18:00",23,"2010-02-06 13:19:00",23
30,"2010-02-06 13:20:00",32,"2010-02-06 13:21:00",39
30,"2010-02-06 13:21:00",11,"2010-02-06 13:21:00",23
30,"2010-02-06 13:21:00",76,"2010-02-06 13:22:00",32
```

which the corresponding datatypes in each field is the following:
cust_id: varchar()
date_removed: datetime
station_removed: int
date_arrived: datetime
station_arrived: int

Next, I was asked to make a query to get the count over every station used along the day, to get a table like this one:

```
station   2010-02-02   2010-02-05  2010-02-06
56            2             0           0
66            1             0           0
32            0             1           2
14            0             2           0
85            0             2           0
8             0             0           1
23            0             0           2
11            0             0           1
76            0             0           1
77            1             0           0
20            0             1           1
39            0             0           1
```

where the columns are the days and the rows are each station. I'm not a very good mySQL user neither.

Could somebody help me on this one?.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Generally, issues of data display are best handled at the application level (e.g. a simple php loop)- assuming that's available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query :

```
 select stations.name as station, 

 (select count(*) from table where date(date_arrived)='2010-02-02' and (station_removed=stations.name or station_arrived=stations.name)) as '2010-02-02'
 (select count(*) from table where date(date_arrived)='2010-02-05' and (station_removed=stations.name or station_arrived=stations.name)) as '2010-02-05'
 (select count(*) from table where date(date_arrived)='2010-02-06' and (station_removed=stations.name or station_arrived=stations.name)) as '2010-02-06'

 from

(select station_removed as name from table
  union
 select station_arrived from table ) stations ;
```

Comment: This did the trick perfectly!  Now, I'm only have one last question.
If I have a large number of dates on my table. is there any possibility to put all of them in a single query?


thank you :)

Comment: @user1984838, looking at your data set, you have to create a select query for each kind of date in your parent select statement.